# what should I do about the error in the Keycloak and ADFS application "Client does not have a public key"?

Tags: gitlab, keycloak, single-sign-on, saml, adfs

I have Keycloak 23.0.4 configured with ADFS (SAML) as an IDP.

The mappings are configured so that from ADFS I receive data about email, first name, last name, as well as which groups the AD user belongs to

There is also a Giltab CE login client.

After I click LOGIN SSO on the page, it redirects to ADFS web, where I enter the user’s AD credentials. Then it redirects to the Keycloak web page, with the error Failed to process response.

In the log file there is an error

```
“ERROR [org.keycloak.protocol.saml.SamlProtocol]
(executor-thread-948) failed:
org.keycloak.common.VerificationException:
Client does not have a public key.”
```

What could be the problem?

Client config (for Gitlab CE)

```
` "clientId": "services.my-corp.com/gitlab",
  "name": "GitLab2",
  "description": "GitLab integration with keycloak",
  "rootUrl": "https://services.my-corp.com/gitlab",
  "adminUrl": "https://services.my-corp.com/gitlab/users/auth/saml/callback",
  "baseUrl": "/",
  "surrogateAuthRequired": false,
  "enabled": true,
  "alwaysDisplayInConsole": true,
  "clientAuthenticatorType": "client-secret",
  "redirectUris": [
"https://services.my-corp.com/gitlab/users/auth/saml/callback"
  ],
  "webOrigins": [
"https://258.260.299.283"
  ],
  "notBefore": 0,
  "bearerOnly": false,
  "consentRequired": false,
  "standardFlowEnabled": true,
  "implicitFlowEnabled": false,
  "directAccessGrantsEnabled": true,
  "serviceAccountsEnabled": false,
  "publicClient": true,
  "frontchannelLogout": true,
  "protocol": "saml",
  "attributes": {
"saml.force.post.binding": "true",
"saml.multivalued.roles": "false",
"post.logout.redirect.uris": "+",
"saml.server.signature.keyinfo.ext": "false",
"saml.signing.certificate": "MI2I-----------Bdf=",
"saml.signature.algorithm": "RSA_SHA256",
"saml.client.signature": "true",
"saml.signing.private.key": "MI2Ies---------C1jls=",
"saml.allow.ecp.flow": "false",
"saml.server.signature.keyinfo.xmlSigKeyInfoKeyNameTransformer": "CERT_SUBJECT",
"saml.assertion.signature": "true",
"saml.encrypt": "true",
"login_theme": "keycloak",
"saml.server.signature": "true",
"saml_idp_initiated_sso_url_name": "services.my-corp.com/gitlab",
"exclude.session.state.from.auth.response": "false",
"saml.artifact.binding.identifier": "sdsdcvJFzqwek=",
"saml.artifact.binding": "false",
"saml_force_name_id_format": "false",
"tls.client.certificate.bound.access.tokens": "false",
"saml.authnstatement": "true",
"display.on.consent.screen": "false",
"saml_name_id_format": "username",
"saml.onetimeuse.condition": "false",
"saml_signature_canonicalization_method": "http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"
   },
```

ADFS config
``

```
`“alias”: “saml”,
“displayName”: “ADFS”,
“internalId”: “0959e193-54aa-44d6-a89e-ebd0dadcbf52”,
“providerId”: “saml”,
“enabled”: true,
“updateProfileFirstLoginMode”: “on”,
“trustEmail”: false,
“storeToken”: false,
“addReadTokenRoleOnCreate”: false,
“authenticateByDefault”: false,
“linkOnly”: false,
“firstBrokerLoginFlowAlias”: “first broker login”,
“config”: {
“hideOnLoginPage”: “”,
“validateSignature”: “true”,
“samlXmlKeyNameTranformer”: “KEY_ID”,
“signingCertificate”: “sdiuvhbdfkvjbdfhbIUH&*hKJBHDLSDjcnlsdvhnkjsdvbksdhbvksbhgksdjngkjdfghkdf”,
“postBindingLogout”: “true”,
“nameIDPolicyFormat”: “urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent”,
“postBindingResponse”: “true”,
“singleLogoutServiceUrl”: “https://adfs.my-company.com/adfs/”,
“backchannelSupported”: “true”,
“signatureAlgorithm”: “RSA_SHA256”,
“wantAssertionsEncrypted”: “false”,
“xmlSigKeyInfoKeyNameTransformer”: “CERT_SUBJECT”,
“useJwksUrl”: “true”,
“wantAssertionsSigned”: “false”,
“postBindingAuthnRequest”: “true”,
“forceAuthn”: “false”,
“singleSignOnServiceUrl”: “https://adfs.my-company.com/adfs/”,
“wantAuthnRequestsSigned”: “true”,
“addExtensionsElementWithKeyInfo”: “false”,
“encryptionPublicKey”: “kehbcsuybisdyhvduvlsdvjxlcvjliG&#&ghuhfnldjvnxcljvnxcjkvnNIYHFIUHDOHLKJVLKJVLKCJVLKXJCVLKJXCVLKJCLVKJLC” }``
```

`

I tried to configure idp, client`